# Magento Magmi Offset

Tags: php, magento, import, offset, magmi

I don't know if I'm allowed to ask it here. But I will give it a try.

I've just setup Magmi (MAGento Mass Importer).

I first logged in with the default credentials : magmi:magmi

now i set up an admin account on my magento shop and connected via that one.

Now it gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /magmi_auth.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /magmi_auth.php on line 45
```

I already googled this issue and I got the following answer:

*Specifically this happens if the session is still logged in with the default magmi:magmi and you successfully connect to Magento.

A quick work around is to clear the browsing history, then log in with the Magento credentials.*

I already tried that but this aint working.

someone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `magmi_auth.php` and comment-out the code inside function `validatePass` and return `1`.

```
private function validatePass($hash,$pass)
{
    return 1;
}
```

I cannot tell about privacy, but this can let you go for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**I faced the same issue, please try this:**

- This issue generally occurred due to changing password manually in Database
- So please change the password through the Magento Admin Panel.
- Please input your changed password once again magmi panel.

> **Don't change any code inside magmi files, that is not a good idea.**

Hope it works for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error itself, but I was able to finally get past the offset errors with a fresh install of MAGMI and by changing **Connectivity** to use **magento.xml** instead in the global settings.